# Android Lock the screen in AppWidgetProvider out of an Activity

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-widget

How to create a simple widget that locks the screen without an `Activity`, only in an `AppWidgetProvider`?

[I've tried this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680291/lock-screen-for-android-is-not-working-properly-using-android/11680450#11680450) but the method `getSystemService` does not exist out of an `Activity` context.

Thank you very much for every clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

Call `getSystemService()` on the `Context` passed into `onReceive()`.

Comment: OK thanks... But now I've problem with the method `startActivityForResult` that he cannot find. Ideas?

Comment: @ValerioBozz: That part you have to do from an activity. There is no option for `startActivityForResult()` from anything other than an activity.