# Add Screen Lock In My App

Tags: android

I want to Implement Screen lock in my app like, how Most of the payment gateway based apps do, I have tried using KeyGuardManager , which work after Lollipop only, the problem is my app also supports KitKat, that's why I need help

This is what I have Tried

```
KeyguardManager km = (KeyguardManager)getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
        if(km.isKeyguardSecure()) {

        Intent i = km.createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent("Authentication required", "password");
        startActivityForResult(i, CODE_AUTHENTICATION_VERIFICATION);
    }
    else
        Toast.makeText(this, "No any security setup done by user(pattern or password or pin or fingerprint", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into [Device Administration](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html#lock)

You can set the maximum period of user inactivity that can occur before the device locks. For example:

```
DevicePolicyManager mDPM;
ComponentName mDeviceAdminSample;
...
long timeMs = 1000L*Long.parseLong(mTimeout.getText().toString());
mDPM.setMaximumTimeToLock(mDeviceAdminSample, timeMs);
```

You can also programmatically tell the device to **lock immediately**:

```
DevicePolicyManager mDPM;
mDPM.lockNow();
```

EDIT:

Don't forget to request the permission 
The docs state

> The calling device admin must have requested USES_POLICY_FORCE_LOCK to
>   be able to call this method; if it has not, a security exception will
>   be thrown.

check this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680291/lock-screen-for-android-is-not-working-properly-using-android)

Comment: What are you trying to answer, I am asking for adding system lock security in my own app.

Comment: how to add screen look to your app for Kitkat obviously

Comment: It gets force closed, I added mDPM.lockNow(); on onCreate

Comment: You didn't check the docs? You should request a permission , i'll edit my answer to add the permission so you have the code right away

Comment: yeah please add the permission

Comment: @SaurabhYadav see the link there is an example, I didn;t see the point of copypasting all that code here